# Android app crashes: SQLite NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm working on implementing a e-commerce app, wherein i'm trying to add the selected item into the cart(here my database) using sqlite. I'm getting null pointer exception. My app crashes when i click on add to cart button.

Here's my logcat

```
04-04 00:52:22.626 17150-17150/com.example.rahul.smartshopping E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.rahul.smartshopping, PID: 17150
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:269)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
                                                                                 at com.example.rahul.smartshopping.helper.DatabaseHandler.getQuantity(DatabaseHandler.java:168)
                                                                                 at com.example.rahul.smartshopping.fragments.SearchResultsAdapter$MyPersonalClickListener.onClick(SearchFragment.java:455)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5205)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21162)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here's my Database Handler:

```
package com.example.rahul.smartshopping.helper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mart";

// Cart table name
private static final String TABLE_CART = "cart";

// Cart Table Columns names
private static final String PRODUCT_ID = "product_id";
private static final String PRODUCT_NAME = "product_name";
private static final String PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID = "category_id";
private static final String PRODUCT_PRICE = "product_price";
private static final String PRODUCT_QUANTITY = "product_quantity";
private static final String PRODUCT_WEIGHT = "product_weight";
private static final String PRODUCT_TOTAL_PRICE = "product_total_price";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CART_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CART + "("
            + PRODUCT_ID + " LONG PRIMARY KEY," + PRODUCT_NAME + " TEXT," + PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + PRODUCT_PRICE + " DOUBLE," + PRODUCT_QUANTITY + " INTEGER, " + PRODUCT_WEIGHT + "DOUBLE, " + PRODUCT_TOTAL_PRICE + "DOUBLE " + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CART_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CART);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new contact
public void addProduct(CartConfig cart) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(PRODUCT_ID, cart.getProductID()); // Product Id
    values.put(PRODUCT_NAME, cart.getProductName()); // Product Name
    values.put(PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID, cart.getProductCategoryID());
    values.put(PRODUCT_PRICE, cart.getProductPrice());
    values.put(PRODUCT_QUANTITY, cart.getProductQuantity());
    values.put(PRODUCT_WEIGHT, cart.getProductWeight());
    values.put(PRODUCT_TOTAL_PRICE, cart.getProductTotalPrice());

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CART, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting single product
CartConfig getProduct(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CART, new String[] { PRODUCT_ID,
                    PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID, PRODUCT_PRICE, PRODUCT_QUANTITY, PRODUCT_WEIGHT, PRODUCT_TOTAL_PRICE }, PRODUCT_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    CartConfig cart = new CartConfig( Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1),
            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)), Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(3)), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)),
            Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(5)), Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(6)));
    // return contact
    return cart;
}

// Getting All Products
public List<CartConfig> getAllProducts() {
    List<CartConfig> productList = new ArrayList<CartConfig>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CART;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            CartConfig cart = new CartConfig();
            cart.setProductID(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(0)));
            cart.setProductName(cursor.getString(1));
            cart.setProductCategoryID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
            cart.setProductPrice(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(3)));
            cart.setProductQuantity(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)));
            cart.setProductWeight(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(5)));
            cart.setProductTotalPrice(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(6)));
            // Adding product to list
            productList.add(cart);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return product list
    return productList;
}

// Updating single Product
public int updateProduct(CartConfig cart) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(PRODUCT_ID, cart.getProductID()); // Product Id
    values.put(PRODUCT_NAME, cart.getProductName()); // Product Name
    values.put(PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID, cart.getProductCategoryID());
    values.put(PRODUCT_PRICE, cart.getProductPrice());
    values.put(PRODUCT_QUANTITY, cart.getProductQuantity());
    values.put(PRODUCT_WEIGHT, cart.getProductWeight());
    values.put(PRODUCT_TOTAL_PRICE, cart.getProductTotalPrice());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_CART, values, PRODUCT_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(cart.getProductID()) });
}

// Deleting single product
public void deleteProduct(CartConfig cart) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CART, PRODUCT_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(cart.getProductID())});
    db.close();
}


// Getting Products Count
public int getProductsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CART;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}

public Cursor getQuantity(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String quantity = "SELECT " + PRODUCT_QUANTITY +"FROM " + TABLE_CART + " WHERE " + PRODUCT_ID +" = " + id;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(quantity, null);
    db.close();
    return c;
}

public void updateQuantity(int tempQty, Double price, Double tempValue, long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String update = "UPDATE " + TABLE_CART + "SET " + tempQty+1 + "," + PRODUCT_TOTAL_PRICE + " = " + price + tempValue +
            "WHERE " + PRODUCT_ID + " = " + id;
}
```

}

Here's my Search Fragment.java class

```
package com.example.rahul.smartshopping.fragments;

public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {

View myFragmentView;
SearchView search;
ImageButton buttonBarcode;
ImageButton buttonAudio;
Typeface type;
ListView searchResults;
String found = "N";

//This arraylist will have data as pulled from server. This will keep cumulating.
ArrayList<Product> productResults = new ArrayList<Product>();
//Based on the search string, only filtered products will be moved here from productResults
ArrayList<Product> filteredProductResults = new ArrayList<Product>();

public SearchFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Context context = getActivity();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //get the context of the HomeScreen Activity
    final WelcomeActivity activity = (WelcomeActivity) getActivity();

    //define a typeface for formatting text fields and listview.

    type = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "fonts/book.ttf");
    myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

    search = (SearchView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.searchView1);
    search.setQueryHint("Start typing to search...");

    searchResults = (ListView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.listview_search);
    buttonBarcode = (ImageButton) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    buttonAudio = (ImageButton) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

    //this part of the code is to handle the situation when user enters any search criteria, how should the
    //application behave?

    buttonBarcode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(activity, Barcode.class),1);
        }
    });

    buttonAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            // Specify free form input
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,"Please start speaking");
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.ENGLISH);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
        }
    });


    //this part of the code is to handle the situation when user enters any search criteria, how should the
    //application behave?

    search.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //Toast.makeText(activity, String.valueOf(hasFocus),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            if (newText.length() > 3) {

                searchResults.setVisibility(myFragmentView.VISIBLE);
                myAsyncTask m = (myAsyncTask) new myAsyncTask().execute(newText);
            } else {

                searchResults.setVisibility(myFragmentView.INVISIBLE);
            }


            return false;
        }

    });
    return myFragmentView;
}

//this captures the result from barcode and populates in the searchView.
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    //this requestCode is for handling the barcode activity.
    if(requestCode==1)
    {
        String barcode=data.getStringExtra("BARCODE");
        if (barcode.equals("NULL"))
        {
            //that means barcode could not be identified or user pressed the back button
            //do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            search.setQuery(barcode, true);
            search.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        }
    }

    //this requestCode is for speechRecognizer. Only this part of the code needs to be added for
    //the implementation of voice to text functionality.

    if (requestCode == 2) {
        ArrayList<String> results;
        results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        //Toast.makeText(this, results.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //if the name has an ' then the SQL is failing. Hence replacing them.
        String text = results.get(0).replace("'","");
        search.setQuery(text, true);
        search.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    }

}

//this filters products from productResults and copies to filteredProductResults based on search text

public void filterProductArray(String newText) {

    String pName;

    filteredProductResults.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < productResults.size(); i++) {
        pName = productResults.get(i).getProductName().toLowerCase();
        if (pName.contains(newText.toLowerCase()) ||
                productResults.get(i).getProductBarcode().contains(newText)) {
            filteredProductResults.add(productResults.get(i));

        }
    }

}

//in this myAsyncTask, we are fetching data from server for the search string entered by user.
class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    JSONParser jParser;
    JSONArray productList;
    String url = new String();
    String textSearch;
    ProgressDialog pd;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        productList = new JSONArray();
        jParser = new JSONParser();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setMessage("Searching...");
        pd.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        pd.show();
        Log.e("On PreExecute", "Hey");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sText) {

        url = "http://192.168.0.5:8080/android/db_search_product.php?pname='" + sText[0] + "'";
        Log.e("URL", "" + url);
        String returnResult = getProductList(url);
        this.textSearch = sText[0];
        Log.e("Return result", "" + returnResult);
        return returnResult;

    }

    public String getProductList(String url) {

        Product tempProduct = new Product();
        String matchFound = "N";
        //productResults is an arraylist with all product details for the search criteria
        //productResults.clear();
        Log.e("get Product details", "Hey");
        try {
            Log.e("try block", "");
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            Log.e("JSONObject", "" + json.toString());

            productList = json.getJSONArray("product");
            Log.e("productList", "" + productList.toString());

            //parse date for dateList
            for (int i = 0; i < productList.length(); i++) {
                tempProduct = new Product();

                JSONObject obj = productList.getJSONObject(i);

                /*tempProduct.setProductCode(obj.getString("ProductCode"));
                tempProduct.setProductName(obj.getString("ProductName"));
                tempProduct.setProductGrammage(obj.getString("ProductGrammage"));
                tempProduct.setProductBarcode(obj.getString("ProductBarcode"));
                tempProduct.setProductDivision(obj.getString("ProductCatCode"));
                tempProduct.setProductDepartment(obj.getString("ProductSubCode"));
                tempProduct.setProductMRP(obj.getString("ProductMRP"));
                tempProduct.setProductBBPrice(obj.getString("ProductBBPrice"));*/
                //my values
                Log.e("Product id",""+obj.getString("product_id"));
                Log.e("Category id",""+obj.getString("category_id"));
                Log.e("Product name", ""+obj.getString("product_name"));
                tempProduct.setProductID(obj.getString("product_id"));
                tempProduct.setProductName(obj.getString("product_name"));
                tempProduct.setCategoryID(obj.getString("category_id"));
                tempProduct.setProductPrice(obj.getString("price"));
                tempProduct.setProductWeight(obj.getString("weight"));
                Log.e("Temp product", "" + tempProduct.toString());

                Log.e("PID", ""+tempProduct.getProductID());
                Log.e("CID", "" + tempProduct.getCategoryID());
                Log.e("PName", "" + tempProduct.getProductName());

                //check if this product is already there in productResults, if yes, then don't add it again.
                matchFound = "N";

                for (int j = 0; j < productResults.size(); j++) {

                    if (productResults.get(j).getProductID().equals(tempProduct.getProductID())) {
                        matchFound = "Y";
                    }
                }

                if (matchFound == "N") {
                    productResults.add(tempProduct);
                }

            }

            return ("OK");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
            return ("Exception Caught");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        Log.e("On PostExecute", "Hey");

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("Exception Caught")) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to connect to server,please try later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            pd.dismiss();
        } else {


            //calling this method to filter the search results from productResults and move them to
            //filteredProductResults
            filterProductArray(textSearch);
            searchResults.setAdapter(new SearchResultsAdapter(getActivity(), filteredProductResults));
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

}

```
class SearchResultsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    private ArrayList<Product> productDetails = new ArrayList<Product>();
    int count;
    Typeface type;
    Context context;

    //constructor method
    public SearchResultsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> product_details) {

        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        this.productDetails = product_details;
        this.count = product_details.size();
        this.context = context;
        type = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/book.ttf");

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return productDetails.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        Product tempProduct = productDetails.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_search, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.product_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            holder.product_mrp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_mrp);
            holder.product_mrpvalue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_mrpvalue);
            holder.product_weight = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_weight);
            holder.product_weight_value = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_weight_value);
            holder.product_category_id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_category_id);
            holder.getProduct_category_id_value = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_category_id_value);
            holder.addToCart = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.add_cart);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.product_name.setText(tempProduct.getProductName());
        holder.product_name.setTypeface(type);

        holder.product_mrp.setTypeface(type);

        holder.product_mrpvalue.setText(tempProduct.getProductPrice());
        holder.product_mrpvalue.setTypeface(type);

        holder.product_weight.setTypeface(type);

        holder.product_weight_value.setText(tempProduct.getProductWeight());
        holder.product_weight_value.setTypeface(type);

        holder.product_category_id.setTypeface(type);

        holder.getProduct_category_id_value.setText(tempProduct.getCategoryID());
        holder.getProduct_category_id_value.setTypeface(type);

        holder.addToCart.setOnClickListener(new MyPersonalClickListener("button_addtocart", tempProduct, context));

        return convertView;
    }
```

This is a customized listener

```
    public class MyPersonalClickListener extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
    {

        String button_name;
        Product prod_name;
        int tempQty;
        double tempValue;
        SQLiteDatabase sqLite;
        DatabaseHandler db;
        Context context;

        //constructor method
        public MyPersonalClickListener(String button_name, Product prod_name, Context context)
        {
            this.prod_name = prod_name;
            this.button_name = button_name;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            // in this section, we are going to add items to cart
            //if the item is already there in cart, then increase the quantity by 1, else add the item to cart
            //if the quantity of the item has reached 10, then do nothing ---this is just a specific logic where
            //i did not want any item with quantity more than 10, but if you choose not to, then just comment out
            //the code.
            //sqLite=context.openOrCreateDatabase("mart", context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
            Log.e("ProductID", "" + prod_name.getProductID());

            //Cursor cc = sqLite.rawQuery("SELECT quantity FROM CART WHERE product_id ="+Long.parseLong(prod_name.getCategoryID()), null);
            Cursor cc = db.getQuantity(Long.parseLong(prod_name.getCategoryID()));

            if (cc.getCount()== 0)
            {
                //product not already there in cart..add to cart
                /*sqLite.execSQL("INSERT INTO CART (product_id, category_id, product_name, quantity"+
                        ", price, total_price, weight) VALUES("+
                        prod_name.getProductID()+",'"+ prod_name.getCategoryID()+ "','" +
                        prod_name.getProductName()+"','"+ 1 +"',"+
                        Integer.parseInt(prod_name.getProductPrice())+","+ Integer.parseInt(prod_name.getProductPrice())+","+
                        Integer.parseInt(prod_name.getProductWeight())+")");*/
                db.addProduct(new CartConfig(Long.parseLong(prod_name.getProductID()), prod_name.getProductName(),
                        Integer.parseInt(prod_name.getCategoryID()), Double.parseDouble(prod_name.getProductPrice()),
                        1,Double.parseDouble(prod_name.getProductWeight()),
                        Double.parseDouble(prod_name.getProductValue())));

                Toast.makeText(context,"Item "+prod_name.getProductName()+" added to Cart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {

                //product already there in cart
                if(cc.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do{
                        tempQty=cc.getInt(0);
                        tempValue = cc.getInt(1);
                    }while(cc.moveToNext());
                }

                if (tempQty < 10)
                {
                    /*sqLite.execSQL("UPDATE CART SET quantity = "+ (tempQty+1)+",total_price = "+
                            (Integer.parseInt(prod_name.getProductPrice())+tempValue)+" WHERE product_id ="+
                            prod_name.getProductID());*/
                    db.updateQuantity(tempQty, Double.parseDouble(prod_name.getProductPrice()), tempValue, Long.parseLong(prod_name.getCategoryID()));

                    Toast.makeText(context,"Item "+prod_name.getProductName()+" added to Cart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            sqLite.close();

        }

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView product_name;
        TextView product_mrp;
        TextView product_mrpvalue;
        //TextView product_bb;
        //TextView product_bbvalue;
        //TextView product_savings;
        //TextView product_savingsvalue;
        //TextView qty;
        //TextView product_value;
        TextView product_weight;
        TextView product_weight_value;
        TextView product_category_id;
        TextView getProduct_category_id_value;
        Button addToCart;

    }
}
```

Comment: you are posting too much information that instead of helping us to help you is confusing us about where the error is at.... clean a little bit the post

Comment: try `db = new DatabaseHandler(this,null.null,1);` instead of `db = new DatabaseHandler(this);` in **MyPersonalClickListener**

Comment: Not sure how or why you extended an Activity for a simple click listener

Answer (score 3):

This is your problem:

> ```
> new MyPersonalClickListener(...)
> ```

and

> ```
> class MyPersonalClickListener extends Activity
> ```

You cannot instantiate activities with `new`. They don't get correctly set up and you cannot use such instances for things you'd want an `Activity` for, such as to be used as `Context`.

Remove the `extends Activity` and use the `context` member variable you're already passing in where you need a `Context` such as passing to your `DatabaseHandler` constructor.